# MSSQL Вывести строки с условием

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть такая таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вывести все строки, кроме тех где при статусе = 4 поле start_date = close_date, т.е. в данном случае будет вся таблица, но без первой строки ?

Comment: Где пример **ваших** попыток это реализовать?

Comment: Пытаюсь вывести с помощью `where`. Реально ли сделать используя этот оператор?

Comment: Да реально, именно этот оператор вам и нужен.

Comment: `status != 4 OR start_date != close_date`

Comment: @Mike опубликуешь ответом?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Mike дал верный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1070559/#comment1836661_1070559) в комментарии:

```
status != 4 OR start_date != close_date
```